# How to make my Ubuntu an internet gateway for my Android phone

Tags: linux, proxy, android, gateway, squid

I want to use the internet of my school on my Android, the problem is they have a Squid proxy, and many applications on my phone don't use the proxy at all.

The obvious solution is to install a transparent proxy on my Android to force all applications to connect through it. The problem is that I need to root the phone to make it work, and I don't want to do it because it's not really my phone and rooting is a little risky-

Another solution, which is safer, is to make my computer run as a gateway, so I put my Ubuntu IP in the gateway parameter of the phone.

I'm running a small proxy on my ubuntu (cntlm), so I redirect the Android traffic to it. I did it with "iptables" as follows:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.1.118 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8888
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.1.118 -p udp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8888
```

10.0.1.118 is the IP of the phone, 8888 is the port of cntlm (proxy on my PC).

Now, on the phone: When I enter `www.google.com` on the navigator I get nothing (web site not found, error message of Firefox).

But, when I enter `http://74.125.143.101` (IP of Google) I get an error message from the school proxy (so it worked in some way – my PC redirected the traffic of the phone to the Squid proxy).

The error message is :

> The requested URL could not be retrieved
>   while trying to process the request
>   get / http/1.1
>   host 74.125.143.101
>   user-Agent ...
>   ...

I think the problem is in the "GET" header,it should be `GET 74.125.143.101 HTTP/1.1`. But I don't understand what's happening, and I'm a certified CCNA.

Comment: If you did this using NAT, wouldn't the MAC address of the phone be sent unmodified?  I would assume the proxy authenticates with a particular device, and thus it's rejecting the packets from your phone.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

on the phone configure same proxy port as you use on ubuntu and configure proxy IP as IP of ubuntu server.

do this on your ubuntu

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 1.1.1.1  -j SNAT --to 1.2.3.4
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 1.1.1.1 -d  1.2.3.4   -j DNAT --to 5.6.7.8
```

1.1.1.1 is phone IP

1.2.3.4 is ubuntu IP

5.6.7.8 is proxy server IP

and enable IP forwarding

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: I don't want at all to enter the proxy on the phone, because most applications do not support the proxy

for ex skype: even if i enter the proxy of the school, it doesn't work, and i enter a proxy on my windows that i developed to debug application, i see that skype doesn't use the proxy at all

Comment: OK..in that case you can use gateway as you are using now and use this.. iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 1.1.1.1 -d  1.2.3.4 -p tcp  --destination-port  80  -j DNAT --to 5.6.7.8

Comment: And for skype check if its trying to use UPnP

Comment: The squid proxy require an NTLM authentication, this is why i'm using CNTLM on my ubuntu. so how should be the iptables commande ?
thanks a lot for your responses

Comment: the GET request looks fine except. it should have the Hostnme and not the IP(it surely wont work with shared hosts.i.e. multiple sites hosted on a single IP). when you are not configuring proxy on the phone ,it will try to send  a DNS request and wait for a  response before it can initiate a HTTP connection.

Comment: I thought about a DNS server,just to test I entered directly the IP of Google to skip DNS resolution, but i don't understand why it doesn't appear in the get header

Comment: the get request that you are seeing is correct  and expected. host is IP in this case and / is the path on the host.

Comment: so, why the squid proxy return an error ? what do you suggest ?
again thanks a lot for your responses and for your time

Comment: Squid server typically has ACL's configured to allow/deny websites , therefore its possible your administrator has allowed only actual hostname in Host field and not IP's (in order to block sites..Its not feasible to have IP ACL's for internet because website IP can change and also one IP may have multiple websites..blocking that IP may block sites which were not intended to be blocked. ).. The easy option here i see is to configure dnsmasq on ubuntu and use it as DNS server for phone

Comment: I will install a DNS server on my ubuntu
but with my pc i can access google with it's IP, so it's not a problem of an ACL,
also I configured firefox on my pc to connect through a proxy that i developed to see the traffic that the browser sent, and when i enter google's ip,the GET header is : GET http://74.125.143.101/ HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting absolutely everything. Including DNS traffic. This does not work; CNTLM doesn't proxy DNS.

Try explicitly allowing port 53 through unmolested:

`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 10.0.1.118 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 10.0.1.118 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: yeah, that's right. It get nothing when I enter the web site name.
I added a DNS server and the appropriate iptables commande. I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the add :

1- A DNS server : and redirect the DNS traffic to it, and the rest of the udp traffic to CNTLM

This doesn't solve the problem entirely, I get the same error whether I enter the web site name or it's IP  (before installing DNS server I get the error just when I enter the web site IP, so DNS resolution worked)

2- After analyzing the traffic from the phone in the cases with/without proxy, I get this :

***without the proxy***

get / http/1.1

host 74.125.143.101

user-Agent ...

..

***with the proxy***

get 74.125.143.101/ http/1.1

host 74.125.143.101

user-Agent ...

so the solution is to add the host name to get header, I will write an app that does

I'm sure it will work :D